# get DataKey in GridView's OnRowCommand event

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise

```
protected void OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Select")
            {
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
                int index = row.RowIndex;
                int employeeID = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewNewsFeed.DataKeys[index].Value);
            }

<asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Title" >
```

'>

```
        }
    }
```

I get this error ... DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'employeeID'.